# Lat Long to State Plane conversion

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, convert, arcgis-rest-api, latitude-longitude, state-plane

I am using the ESRI javascript API and I have a set of lat/long points I need to convert to a state plane coordinate system. My spatial reference is wkid 3418.

I can easily use the GeometryService to project the state plane to lat/long, but need to go in the opposite direction.

I was looking at the REST API for ArcGIS and saw a setting `transformFoward`. Is this the setting I need to go in that direction? (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000pv000000)

What are ways I can do this conversion?

Comment: The geometry by default should be using 4326, but instead assign it 4269 (NAD 1983), then your outSR will be 3418. transformForward is for geographic/datum transformations between two GCS.

Comment: @mkennedy Sorry I must say that I am new at this. How can I verify my service is using 4326? I regularly project my map points from my map to latlong using this service, doesn't that mean that service is using 3418? How could I assign that to 4269?

Comment: You might like to look into proj4js to do client-side transforms.  See https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to specify `transformForward`.  Just set the `inSR` to `4269` (from [Geographic Coordinate Systems](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r300000105000000), for GCS_North_American_1983), and the `outSR` parameter to 3418.